# SqlDbType enumeration mapping - C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures, sqldbtype

What value in the `SqlDbType` enumeration should I use for the `numeric` T-SQL data type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decimal.

See this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx

Comment: Note that the above link shows `SqlType` mappings, not `SqlDbType`, although in this case the mapping is the same, `NUMERIC` to `Decimal`. Here are the full mappings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that `SqlDbType.Decimal` is the closest.

- [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)