# Why is this stored procedure not updating data in a database?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure with a hardcoded value. The command executes successfully without any errors. But data is not updating in the database. If I run that stored procedure with SQL Server, data is updating. What's my mistake?

C# code

```
using (SqlTransaction sqlTrans = con.BeginTransaction())
{
    using (SqlCommand AdjustTax = new SqlCommand("GP_SOP_AdjustTax", con, sqlTrans))
    {
        try
        {
            AdjustTax.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_SOPType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
            AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_SOPNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "stdinv2278";
            AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_AdjustAmount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0.04;
            AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@O_iError", SqlDbType.Int, 250);
            AdjustTax.Parameters["@O_iError"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            if (con == null || con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            AdjustTax.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int Error = (int)AdjustTax.Parameters["@O_iError"].Value;

            if (Error == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tax is Adjusted");
            }
            if (Error != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error No:" + Error1);
            }

            sqlTrans.Commit();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            sqlTrans.Rollback();
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

SQL Server code

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @O_iError int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[GP_SOP_AdjustTax]    
        @IN_SOPType = 3,   
        @IN_SOPNo = 'stdinv2278',    
        @IN_AdjustAmount = 0.04,    
        @O_iError = @O_iError OUTPUT

SELECT  @O_iError as N'@O_iError'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Please confirm about the DB Type Int of third input parameter i.e. @IN_AdjustAmount

Comment: thanks for reply. type is numaric

Comment: If type is numaric..then which type have i set in c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is being caused by this line:

```
AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_AdjustAmount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0.04;
```

Since the type is `SqlDbType.Int` and you are passing in 0.04, that value is most likely getting rounded to 0. Without seeing the contents of the actual stored procedure, I can only guess that passing in a value of 0 for that parameter either causes the stored procedure to skip the update, or the calculation that the stored procedure does results in the column being updated to the same value it originally had.

I would try changing that line to:

```
AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_AdjustAmount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 0.04M
```

**EDIT**
`Decimal` is the proper mapping for the `Numeric` Sql Type, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604110/sqldbtype-enumeration-mapping-c-sharp).

Comment: Let me know why you included 'M'(0.04M).

Comment: `M` just means `decimal`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try SqlDbType.Decimal:

```
AdjustTax.Parameters.Add("@IN_AdjustAmount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 0.04;
```